# How can I connect to server when trying to use postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, localhost, database-connection

I get this error message (see below) and do not know what to do about it.

Error message:

"psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)  Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? "

I am using Windows 10 (64bit) and have tried the same thing on Kali and Ubuntu and still was not able to use postgresql.
Does anyone have a suggestion what do to? However, please use "language" that I can understand or at least look up simply because I am new to programming (in general). Thank you

P. S. I tried various different things such as using pgAdmin to change ports but cannot solve a problem. I do not know if this is important but I istalled postgresql via Binaries because regular Installer was giving an error message telling me that comspec does not point to cmd.exe even though it actually did...

Comment: Did you start the database server? Please check the log files

Comment: How exactly did you install Postgres? Did you run initdb and create a Windows service? If yes, is the Windows service running?

Comment: I installed it from https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries and just followed instructions for installation from this video: https://youtu.be/cYFYfYXObgA. I do not know what initdb is, I am sorry.  @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

If you

1. properly set up your db (installation and initialization using initdb), and if you
2. have your data directory containing your `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` among other things, and you
3. properly started the postgresql service,

then I can assume your problem is in the connection string.

Try to include the superusername and/or db name, your error maybe due to psql connecting to user `localhost` which does not exist inside your db.

Try to run `psql` with `-U` and `-d` options:

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres
```